# How to extend a JavaScript object/function to expose API methods after initialization?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I want to create a javascript application that works like this:

- Has a function/namespace called `bm`.
- At the start bm is just a function that has a method called `setup`, so two things are possible: calling `bm()` or defining some setup variables calling `bm.setup(settings)`.
- To use the library and expose the API `bm` has to be initialized first by calling the function: `bm(url, options)`. If initialized succesfully, the API should be exposed so `bm` now has additional methods like `bm.method1`, `bm.method2`,...

I don't know how exactly is this possible, so I would like to hear any ideas, examples or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's nice is functions are first-class objects, so you can add methods to them. Then your primary instance creating function just needs to check and make sure its called as an instance:

```
var bm = function(settings) {
    if (!(this instanceof bm)) {
        return new bm(settings);
    }

    // Now we are sure we are working with
    // a new instance. Let's do stuff here 
    // to our new object.
}

bm.setup = function(settings) {
    return new bm(settings);
}
```

This can be called any of these ways:

```
var myObj = new bm();

var myObj = new bm(settings);

var myObj = bm();

var myObj = bm(settings);

var myObj = bm.setup(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like...

```
function bp ( url, options ) {
    if ( !url || !options)
        return 'You fail mister';

    //declare stuff here:
    this.aMethod = function() {...};
    this.anAttribute = true;

    return this;
}
bp.setup = function( settings ) {
    return new bp( predefinedURL, settings);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here. You might want to add a callback function to the bm(), which is called when API is initialized, like this:

```
onAPIInitialized = function() { use the API };
bm(url, options, onAPIInitialized);
```

You can add functions to bm like to an ordinary object:

```
bm.method1 = function(...) {}
```